# Amazon Deeplens device is offline after successful registration, can't deploy project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-deeplens

I'm all set following the installation instructions but suddenly the cam went off-line in the AWS Console (Device Status: Offline)(when I installed the device the status was online)
Running version 1.2.3 with Linux kernel 4.10.17
I can ssh into the cam, I have a working wifi connection in the cam, I can update the cam software and I can see the video stream on the cam.

Do I need to restart an awscam service (if there's such service)? Or maybe reboot the camera (just did that, no dice)?

I have no idea why this is happening (I haven't updated the camera software or Ubuntu)
BTW the effect of this is that the deployment of a project to the cam gets stuck (blue message with 0 progress)

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I factory-reseted the device, set it up again and then it worked fine.

Comment: I had this same issue with a v1.1 device. Needed to do the paperclip (tiny pin) reset again with reset button, connected to devices wifi, browser connect to http://deeplens.config on device, that time it prompted to do a software updated and fixed issue and the device came online and successfully deployed the project I was trying to deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this can happen regularly as I power on/off the camera daily as I experiment with it. I've found re-install the awscam module works every time. You need SSH onto the device and run the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall awscam
```

Wait about thirty seconds for the newly installed awscam to restart and you will see the device come back online. You don't need to Re-register the device or edit settings, just re-install awscam. Some more details are contained on the AWS forums, for example : https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=281899

Answer (score 1):

We found that the AWS DeepLens has a single network adapter running both wifi hotspot and wifi connection. If you connect to its hotspot functionality it will drop the main wifi connection. Then it will try reconnect to wifi and drop your phone/machine connection and repeat this process at will.

Connecting a monitor (mini-HDMI to HDMI cable), mouse and keyboard will allow you to see what it's actually doing. Ours was stuck on GUI password prompt for wifi.
Default password for access on ours was "aws_cam" which is not in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I reset the DeepLens camera and then restarted it. That solved the offline issue I got after removing the project from the device.